# What happens after you deregister an EC2 instance from Elastic Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-elb

Suppose I have a couple of web servers behind an ELB instance. I want to take down half of them to do software update. Suppose my application have some potentially longer requests (say take up to 30 seconds because the database is slow). I don't want to just shutdown the servers and leave users with an error. Can I deregister the instance from ELB to stop any further requests from hitting the instance, but allow some time for the instance to finish its current requests before shutting it down? Will the ELB still forward the responses from a recently deregistered instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=231571

> We just ran a test of ELB both with health check and with manually removing an instance from the ELB, and all existing connections were dropped rudely almost immediately (within about a second).

Amazon's response:

> We are aware of the pain that this behavior can cause our customers, and feedback like this helps us better understand the real impact and importance of the issue. Please keep it coming.

Don't count on a quick fix, this is still the case two years later.

Comment: wow, this sucks. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: @jz87 Yeah, it does. I do suggest adding your comments to the thread - they really do prioritize things at least in part by number of requests.

Comment: Is there any other way to tell ELB to stop sending requests to an instance? I would like to be able to allow an instance to finish its current requests before shutting it down. Otherwise you risk all sorts of nasty things like data loss.

Comment: @jz87 One of the recommendations in that thread is to spin up a new ELB, point DNS at it, and wait for the (hopefully very short) TTL to expire before removing the old ELB from service.

Comment: On June 10 2013 an Amazon employee (BenF) mentioned on the thread that the AWS developers are now actively working on a solution to this problem.  The post mentioned thought that there is not yet a clear timeframe for a solution.  See [this page for the post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=61278&start=75&tstart=0).

Answer (score 4):

Because i recently used this feature myself, and there is solution to the problem asked/described (not covered in the existing comments/answers):

Its called Connection Draining and can be set in the ELB Configuration. You define a timeout (defaults to 300 seconds) that the ELB keeps the Connection open to finish, before dropping them.

Here is a Blog Post explaining how to set up Connection draining in your ELB: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/aws/elb-connection-draining-remove-instances-from-service-with-care/

And the AWS Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-conn-drain.html

Hm, i can not post more thant 2 links because i lack the reputation ....
If you go on github.com and search in the awslabs account for aws-codedeploy-samples you will find shell scripts that unregister instances from ELBs.